# Any good references or tools available for converting ASP to ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

What tools, practices, or documentation have you used in your conversion process that you would recommend to others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try Microsoft's

[ASP to ASP.NET 1.x Migration Assistant](http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived/migration-assistants/asp-to-aspnet/)

> The ASP to ASP.NET v1.x Migration
>   Assistant is designed to help you
>   convert ASP pages and applications to
>   ASP.NET. It does not make the
>   conversion process completely
>   automatic, but it will speed up your
>   project by automating some of the
>   steps required for migration.

I guess it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

We've converted a few ASP classic apps to .net, and are in the process of converting another.

What we did was first to split them into two groups - ones that we would convert completely, before replacing the old with the new, and then the ones we could convert incrementally.

For that second group, it was useful to build some header and sidebar controls for the app that also held some of the more programmy parts - security, navigation and such, and then use an iframe for holding the ASP classic stuff, in the areas we haven't gotten to converting yet.

It's been pretty painless, as we can pull out the old, and insert the new on our own schedule, rather than having to get the entire massive app rewritten before moving forward.  It's also helped us be able to tailor the changes and new features to our customers' needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick and dirty way to convert from ASP to ASP.Net since ASP.Net supports inline coding that was used in ASP Classic. However, you wouldn't be taking full advantage of ASP.Net with that approach.

The bad news is there's no easy way to convert from ASP Classic to ASP.Net the "right" way. They are such different technologies there's no streamlined conversion process.

Answer (score 0):

one is a scripting language and other compiled so the overall paradigm itself is completely different and I am really skeptical that there would be anyway to convert / migrate your app from classic asp to asp.net, if you intend to use asp.net the way its meant to be.