# Convert ASP into ASP.NET

Tags: vb.net

#### Duplicate

> [Any good references or tools available for converting from ASP to ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821230/any-good-references-or-tools-available-for-converting-asp-to-asp-net)

How i can convert an ASP Classic web page into an ASP.NET web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try doing anything automated - the name is about the only thing that is really the same. The best approach is to start from scratch - having the existing working app as a spec can make develpopment quite quick.