# how to use asp pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I want to use asp page in my asp.net application without any  modification in asp pages.

further I want to add master page in my .net application.So i need the changes to be reflected in the asp page also.

is it possible....any how?  or any alternative to use this..?

pls suhggest me .....thanx in advance...

Comment: if it's only 1 asp-page, why not rewrite the page to .net?

Comment: no sir its not a single page...

Its a system of multiplae pages with a mess of asp and asp.net pages.

Answer (score 2):

ASP does not have master pages, so you can't use them. The most sensible thing to do is to rewrite the ASP page in ASP.NET, while there are still people around who understand what the ASP page was meant to do. There will otherwise come a time when nobody understands that page.

The closest thing I've seen to what you're looking for is to write an ASP.NET page that refers to the ASP page through an IFRAME. The ASP.NET page can be a content page, referring to the master page, and the ASP page can stay the same.

Comment: how to do that..can you pls tell me something..?

Comment: If you want help, then you'll have to say what error you're getting. Also, check to see if you get this error with _all_ ASP pages, or only this one particular ASP page.

Answer (score 2):

Classic ASP files run without any problems in a ASP.NET website. As soon as you want to mix classic ASP and ASP.NET functionality in one file you will get errors.
Applying master pages to classic ASP files can't be done.

**[EDIT]**
An alternative could be to rewrite the functionality of the ASP pages into ASP.NET.
There is a SO question about tools for converting from ASP to ASP.NET [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821230/any-good-references-or-tools-available-for-converting-asp-to-asp-net).

Comment: so any alternative for that sir..?

Comment: no sir I cant do this ...b'coz system is too large to convert.I have to work  with limited  options.

Comment: There _will_ come a time when this mess of ASP and ASP.NET pages can no longer be maintained. At some point, those ASP pages will either need to be re-written, or discarded. You want this time to arrive while there are still people available who can understand these old pages, not after such people are dead or gone.

Comment: Hi John, I write VBScript / classic ASP a lot. So understanding these 'old pages' is no problem for me (if I may say so) and I know what mess it is to combine 'old' with 'new' ;-) So I'm happy to see you agree.

Comment: I don't mean understanding the code, so much as understanding them from a business point of view. Besides, are you immortal? Will you never leave the job? Does the "next guy in line" also have your abilities with classic ASP? I'm not talking about this happening in the next year or so, but I can tell you that fewer and fewer people want to have "Classic ASP" on their resume. You may very well reach a point where you are competing to hire them, and have pay top dollar for them - or maybe not find them at all.

Answer (score 1):

i have used asp and asp.net vb together when i was learning
my method was to use jquery to put my asp classic generated html into
designated divs... as my leaning increased i needed to use this method less and less
its a great way to pick up asp.net C# when moving from a VB background when you dont really have time to learn, like at work.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty way: Make a HTTP request from the ASP.NET code to the .asp page and store the response in a web control. It's not pretty, but it works.